# Firebase ML Kit: Pre-Trained Models

Tags: android, tensorflow, face-detection, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I can see there are 3 pre-trained models included in the [assets](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit/app/src/main/assets) folder of the ML-Kit sample app.

Please help me understand

- Which of these models correspond to face detection?
- What is the data set used to train these models?

Answer (score 0):

Those are custom models provided to highlight the ML Kit functionality that allows you to bring your own TFLite models.

The pre-trained APIs, also known as Base APIs (text recognition, image labeling, etc) get added by including the appropriate libraries in your app's gradle file. No need to include anything in your assets folder. See an example here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text